# Unexplained gap on IE and Firefox

Tags: css, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using an accordion slide in my site and I've noticed that on IE and Firefox I get a weird gap of 20 pixels at the top of the slider.

I've checked the CSS back to back for some padding to the UL or the LI or even the slider itself but couldn't find any. It works perfectly on Chrome.

Read many post suggesting this to adjust the line-height but it didn't work for me.

How can I resolve this issue?

http://www.rom.guywalderonline.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY THIS>>>

```
#slider {
height: 0px; /*IMPORTANT*/
background: url('../images/romold.jpg') top right no-repeat;
background-color: #434749;
}
```

This 100% works, if you have any problems please comment back....

Comment: Thanks but this solution not only didn't fix the problem but removed my background image as well.

Comment: @user3509934 No, I think that there is a style which is inherited which is causing this bug. Can you give me a link to your background image that is disappearing. thanks

Comment: Hi, thank you so much but I solved the problem. It was the height of the top menu li that pushed the slider down. Somehow Chrome could over look this conflict but IE and Firefox couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following code to your template css file, it willl remove the gap:

```
#slider .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    min-height: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: @user3509934 - ahh sorry, made a slight mistake in the code. Try again now ;)

Comment: I saw the . instead if the # and tried it already, didn't work either :(

Comment: Solved. The problem was with the height of the top menu li.